# Some particles go straight through collision objects

Tags: particles, physics, collision

[image]

As the title says, some particles don't seem to be effected by an object with collision enabled on it at all.

[image: particles]

I found a couple threads on this, but they were all really old, and the things suggested in them, like enabling "size deflect" in the physics tab of the particle system, doesn't work for me, as I don't want my particles colliding with themselves.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try subdividing your collider.

Comment: Subdivided 100 times, then twice again, same thing happens still.

Comment: Well, I just found a sort of answer. If I duplicate the collision object and move it further down the direction of travel of the particles just a tad bid, it catches some more of the stray particles. I needed at least 4 planes to stop all particles, but at least it's a solution to my specific issue. It's kinda a hack solution so I'm not posting it as an answer.

Comment: I had a similar problem way back, if you don't need the particles, you can kill them on collision. Apparently they collide, but if they are fast, they don't "realize" it until they're "through". Maybe that still works.

Comment: I need them, so that won't work unfortunately.

Comment: If you just need them to stick there, there's an option to render dead particles.